# Can't get my Github workflow up and running

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm trying to get my automated testing set up for this project and I can't get the workflow to run. Things I've checked:

- tests are running locally when I call the commands in the test.yml file
- file is in myrepo/.github/workflows/test.yml
- Local and remote branch are both main
- Workflow also didn't run when I did a pull request
- I've tried a few different methods of checking the syntax

The code has pushed and it's in the repo; there's just no tests being run.

The code:

```
name: Test
on: [push]

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-16.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Unit Tests
        run: npm test --watchAll=false
      - name: E2E Tests
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          start: npm start
          wait-on: 'http://localhost:8000'
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit: I had changed the name of the repo, and when I did, I managed to add another folder with the same name, so my directory was actually my-repo/my-repo/.github/workflows. Took out the extra my-repo folder and it worked fine. ‍♂️

Comment: This workflow will run on every push you make. You could add a workflow_dispatch event to trigger it manually through the Github repo Actions tab as well for tests. Moreover, what is your repository structure? Could you add it to the question just for checking?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My repo and local both have "main" branches; my repo has "ci" as well, which I was initially using to try to implement this. It's been merged and now I can't figure out how to delete it.

I can't trigger the workflow manually because GitHub isn't recognizing it in the first place, so when I go to "Actions" there's nothing to trigger.

Comment: The workflow `.yml` file isn't present on the repo `main` branch?

Comment: It's in /my-repo/.github/workflows/test.yml in both ```main``` and ```ci```.

Also, I just added the learn-github-actions.yml workflow to the same folder, copied and pasted from the tutorial, and it's not working either.

Comment: Is it a public repo you can share to see what can be wrong? (Otherwise, here are some personal repos that could be used as references: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/useful-actions + https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions)

Comment: Found it. I had changed the name of the repo, and when I did I somehow managed to add an extra folder in there so the structure was my-repo/my-repo/.github/workflows. Local was still just my-repo/. github/workflows so I couldn't see it. Thanks for your help!